# Load Javascript URL inside Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a src url inside of javascript, but its not working..

```
function detectmob() {
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {     
    return 'https://example.com/advertisements.js';   
   } else {

    return false;

   }
}
```

Comment: You're returning a string.  It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here.  Can you provide more about what you mean by loading the url?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I am trying to include this `<script src="https://example.com/advertisements.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` on mobile view only..

Comment: so you wanna append this to the dom if it's mobile?

Comment: @lacostenycoder ye

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add this in the html and define the js file you want to load? For example:

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width <= 800 && screen.height <= 800) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return anything to change the window location.  Instead of return you can use:
    window.location = newUrl;